# Why does ResponseBody and Jackson ObjectMapper don't return the same output?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am using a Spring Boot application.

I have a method in my controller that returns some Resources:

```java
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @GetMapping(value="data/{itemId}/items", produces="application/json")
    public Resources<DataExcerpt> listMyData(@PathVariable("debateId") UUID debateId)){

       List<DataExcerpt> dataExcerpts = dataService
                .listMyData(id)
                .stream()
                .map(d -> this.projectionFactory.createProjection(DataExcerpt.class, d))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new Resources<>(dataExcerpts);
    }
```

This returns something in the form of:

```java
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "items" : [ {
      "position" : {
        "name" : "Oui",
        "id" : "325cd3b7-1666-4c44-a55f-1e7cc936a3aa",
        "color" : "#51B63D",
        "usedForPositionType" : "FOR_CON"
      },
      "id" : "5aa48cfb-5505-43b6-b0a9-5481c895e2bf",
      "item" : [ {
        "index" : 0,
        "id" : "43c2dcd0-6bdb-43b0-be97-2a40b99bc753",
        "description" : {
          "id" : "021ad7cd-4bf1-4dce-9ea7-10980440a049",
          "title" : "Item description",
          "modificationCount" : 0
        }
      } ],
      "title" : "Item title",
      "originalMaker" : {
        "username" : "jeremieca",
        "id" : "cfae1a04-cb00-4ad4-b4e8-6971eff64807",
        "avatarUrl" : "user-16",
        "_links" : {
          "self" : {
            "href" : "http://some-api-link"
          }
        }
      },
      "itemState" : {
        "itemState" : "LIVE",
      },
      "opinionImprovements" : [ ],
      "sourcesJson" : [ ],
      "makers" : [ {
        "username" : "jeremieca",
        "id" : "cfae1a04-cb00-4ad4-b4e8-6971eff64807",
        "avatarUrl" : "user-16",
        "_links" : {
          "self" : {
            "href" : "http://some-api-link"
          }
        }
      } ],
      "modificationsCounter" : 1,
      "originalBuyer" : "fd9b68f9-7c0c-4120-869c-c63d1680e7f0",
      "updateTrace" : {
        "createdOn" : "2020-05-25T08:12:56.846+0000",
        "createdBy" : "cfae1a04-cb00-4ad4-b4e8-6971eff64807",
        "updatedOn" : "2020-05-25T08:12:56.845+0000",
        "updatedBy" : "cfae1a04-cb00-4ad4-b4e8-6971eff64807"
      },
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "some-api-link",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "newEditions" : {
          "href" : "some-api-link",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "makers" : {
          "href" : "http://some-api-link"
        },
        "originalMaker" : {
          "href" : "http://some-api-link"
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

On the other end, I also want to cache these sort of answers inside Redis to avoid running the whole process every time. To do that, I am using Jackson's ObjectMapper to convert my Resources to a string

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(controller.listMyData(id)); // the same function as above
```

*writeValueAsString* output's structure is different from the first one:

```java
"{content: [...], _links: []}"
```

So, when I return from my API with the cache content, the structure is not the same from the structure the controller sends me without the cache.

Why is that?
Is Jackson not able to correctly write as string the Resources Hateoas structures?
Am I missing something?

**EDIT**:

Here is the Resources.class:

```java
package org.springframework.hateoas;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

@XmlRootElement(name = "entities")
public class Resources<T> extends ResourceSupport implements Iterable<T> {
    private final Collection<T> content;

    protected Resources() {
        this(new ArrayList(), (Link[])());
    }

    public Resources(Iterable<T> content, Link... links) {
        this(content, (Iterable) Arrays.asList(links));
    }

    public Resources(Iterable<T> content, Iterable<Link> links) {
        Assert.notNull(content, "Content must not be null!");
        this.content = new ArrayList();
        Iterator var3 = content.iterator();

        while (var3.hasNext()) {
            T element = var3.next();
            this.content.add(element);
        }

        this.add(links);
    }

    public static <T extends Resource<S>, S> Resources<T> wrap(Iterable<S> content) {
        Assert.notNull(content, "Content must not be null!");
        ArrayList<T> resources = new ArrayList();
        Iterator var2 = content.iterator();

        while (var2.hasNext()) {
            S element = var2.next();
            resources.add(new Resource(element, new Link[0]));
        }

        return new Resources(resources, new Link[0]);
    }

    @XmlAnyElement
    @XmlElementWrapper
    @JsonProperty("content")
    public Collection<T> getContent() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(this.content);
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return this.content.iterator();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Resources { content: %s, %s }", this.getContent(), super.toString());
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        } else if (obj != null && obj.getClass().equals(this.getClass())) {
            Resources<?> that = (Resources) obj;
            boolean contentEqual = this.content == null ? that.content == null : this.content.equals(that.content);
            return contentEqual ? super.equals(obj) : false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result += this.content == null ? 0 : 17 * this.content.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your whole `Resources` entity and the whole body of the `listMyData()` function.

Comment: ObjectMapper works well. But just check using a debug point at controller.listMyData(id) before given to ObjectMapper object. Whether the object is getting as you expect

Comment: Edited with additional informations asked by @k-wasilewski

Comment: I meant the `Resources.class`, because we still don't know where is this `content: ...` coming from.

Comment: This is the Resources.class from Spring Hateoas. Added it for reference @k-wasilewski

Comment: According to this guide : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/, in order to use hateoas properly in the controller you need to extend from RepresentationModel, so in your case DataExcerpt needs to extend from RepresentationModel and provide the content

Comment: what the content of ResourceSupport.java

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that when Spring configures your MVC or Spring Boot application with HATEOAS, among other things, it will configure custom Jackson modules for handling the serialization and deserialization process of the `Resources` class and the rest of the object model exposed by the API.

If you want to obtain a similar result, you can do something like the following:

```java
import org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.Jackson2HalModule;

// ...

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(controller.listMyData(id));
```

Comment: @Tagada85 It worked? Did you get the same results in both Spring Boot and Redis cache?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to provide POJOs, extending `hateoas`' `ResourceSupport`, through which the (de-)serialization would go through, eg.

ResourcesJson (the root element)

```
public class ResourcesJson extends ResourceSupport {
    @JsonProperty("_embedded")
    private ResourcesEmbeddedListJson  embedded;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Embedded "wrapper"

```
public class ResourcesEmbeddedListJson extends ResourceSupport {
    private Collection<T> content;

    //getters and setters
}
```

or if you want to make it less ugly, there's this `org.springframework.hateoas.client.Traverson` component.